# Search For a Word and Replace It In Entire File Using Egrep

Tags: grep

How do I search an entire file for a word and replace it with another word using egrep?

Comment: You can't. Use something like `sed` instead.

Comment: @roaima, you want to make that a full answer? it would be the right one. Don' forget sed -r works with extended regular expressions like egrep.

Comment: Everyone, I want to keep this around to point users at. FAQ!.